# not able to install samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I had to uninstall `samba`, because I had configured it wrong. But now when i try to reinstall it using `sudo apt-get install samba smbfs`, I get the output:-

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Package samba is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:`
  samba-common

Package smbfs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

`E: Package 'samba' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'smbfs' has no installation candidate`

I am nor able to download it via `ubuntu` Software center.
Any help is appreciated

Thank you

---

Comment: First uninstall it completely 
       
     Sudo apt-get autoremove samba4 
then reinstall 
             
    Sudo apt-get inst samba4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First uninstall it completely

```
 Sudo apt-get autoremove samba4
```

then reinstall

```
Sudo apt-get install samba4
```

Comment: @ raj, I did it. but samba4 was not found . So i tried Sudo apt-get autoremove samba, which resulted in uninstallation of almost all applications present in my system, including text editors, java, libre office etc